# How can I pass a value when creating a new tab panel with CSJS

Tags: html, dojo, xpages, xpages-extlib

I want to create a new tabbed panel for the Dojo tab container using CSJS like:

```
 dijit.byId('#{id:djTabContainer1}').createTab({ tabTitle: Math.random()});
```

The default tab panel has an panel that will use the iframe tag and I want to pass in the above call the src html attribute to the panel.

**Question :** I can specify a url to load in the iframe. Is there a way to pass this?

It seems like the createTab only does certain tab related parameters like action and tabTitle.

Howard

Comment: my thought: just get an ID of new tab, dig into its content and set target property of iframe. also found this: http://kaoticreality.blogspot.sk/2015/03/xpages-tabcontainer-dynamically-add.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax is somewhat obscure here. Starting with the code in the ExtLib demo app:

XPagesExt.nsf/Core_DynamicTabs.xsp

Change the script in button4 to:

```
dijit.byId('#{id:djTabContainer1}')
    .createTab({
      "newName":'Tab'+Math.random(),
      "newHref":'/XPagesExt.nsf/page5.xsp'})
```

to match the syntax you're requesting.
And, in the tab that's referenced by defaultTabContent, change the title and href to use those passed URL parameters:

```
<xe:djTabPane xp:key="doc" id="djTabPane2"
    title="${javascript:/*load-time-compute*/param.newName}" 
    href="${javascript:/*load-time-compute*/param.newHref}"
```

It will create the tab and will attempt to load the href contents. I'm not seeing it as an iframe though - it's just a container div.

Comment: thanks, if the href works I would not need an iframe. Will give it a try.

Comment: I got it working but having issues setting the tabUniqueKey (so the same document does not open a new tab). Using tabUniqueKey="${javascript:/*load-time-compute*/param.newName}" gives me a client side alert that says "An error occured while updating some of the page. _386.parentNode is null"

Comment: This is my test page http://www.netexperts.com/TestTabContainer.nsf/TabContainerCSJS2.xsp

Comment: Provide the tabUniqueKey to createTab before the submission:
    var newName = 'Tab'+Math.random();
    dijit.byId('#{id:djTabContainer1}')
        .createTab({
            "newName":newName,
            "newHref":'/XPagesExt.nsf/page5.xsp',
            tabUniqueKey: newName})

as well as in the server-side tab (as you have).
That parentNode is null error is when attempting to re-open an existing tab.
When the tabUniqueKey is included in the call to createTab, it will refresh the existing tab instead of attempting to create and populate a new tab with the same id as the existing tab.

Comment: thanks, that works great. However an issue with using HREF in the tabPane (and why I was trying to get an iframe working) is that a button to place the document in the tab into edit mode does not work. It does nothing....Anonymous has Editor access to the document. I was using simple action in the XPage opened via href to switch to edit mode.

Comment: So in that case you can try putting the iframe HTML into the tab panel control on the XPage, and use the url params in a load-time expression as before. Or else if you do the document editing directly in the tab within the button extracting to a custom control if needed, then you'd be using the form within the outer XPage, and the edit mode change and other partial refresh actions would work again.

Comment: Maire, yes, I did your first suggestion (actually with an includePage) and that works fine. Just wanted to point out the issue with href when using an XPage as the url. None of the buttons seem to work. Bug? thanks for your help!  Howard

Comment: The xe:djTabPane href behavior is from dojo. The XPages way would be to partial refresh a section of the current page rather than using 2 separate XPage instances in the same web page. When the tab panel attempts to load the entire page of the href into the div, you get duplicate elements with the same ids, etc. It's not a supported configuration. There isn't an xpages mechanism for loading an entire xpage within an existing page (iframes work but are separate to the existing page). You could generate custom html output that would work with href, but it's not so useful with a regular xpage.

Comment: Thanks Maire for the insight. The iframe approach does work but then you bump into the maximum number of pages on disk issue as the older XPages in the iframe (which are in a tab) get overwritten and lost and the entire XPage reloads and loses all the opened tabs. I think the include Page might be a good work around. Appreciate all your help, Howard